# Using undefined with and without typof()

Tags: javascript

How come these to lines give different result ?

```
if (EventSource !== undefined) { // error

if (typeof(EventSource) !== 'undefined') { // no error
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `EventSource` is not declared, and it's considered a ReferenceError to request the value of an undeclared variable.

The `typeof` operator on the other hand is able to take an identifier as an operand without getting its value, avoiding the error.

---

If this is a local variable, you should heed the ReferenceError, and define it first.

If this is global, and its existence *can't* be known beforehand, you can check it as a property of `window`:

```
if ("EventSource" in window) {
```

or

```
if (window.EventSource !== undefined) {
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing, **ReferenceError: EventSource is not defined** means that the JS engine has no idea who `EventSource` is. It's never heard of it before and it should read something there, but it doesn't know what. The `typeof` operator is protected from that error and returns `'undefined'` instead of throwing an error, just like it does for variables that haven't been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

A variable that is declared without a value is `undefined`.

A variable that is not declared throws an error when you try to use it, but when using `typeof` you avoid that as checking an undeclared variable returns the type `'undefined'`.
It does this because `typeof` is an operator (not a function) that always returns a string, even if you pass it something that is not previously declared.

Answer (score 0):

From the ECMA-262 Standard draft:

**8.7.1 GetValue (V)**: [...] If IsUnresolvableReference(V), throw a **ReferenceError** exception. [...]

**11.4.3 The typeof Operator**: [...] If Type(val) is Reference, then [...] If IsUnresolvableReference(val) is true, return "undefined". [...]

In short, they are different operations that follow different rules.